# Mysql database Join issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

What I want to do is display the routineName and description when the user logged into my system based on what they userID or username is.

I have 3 tables in mySQL database 
user
userid
name
username
password

Routine
RoutineID
RoutineName
Description

UserRoutines
UserRoutinesID
userid
RoutineID

This is my Query So far
SELECT `routine`.`RoutineName`, `routine`.`Description`
FROM `user_routines`, `routine`, `userdetails`
Where 'user_routine'.'userid' = 'user'.'userid'
AND 'user'.username = username = ?; (? is the variable passed from the application)

Comment: Join issues... Ok so where is your code?

Comment: Post the code you tried which didnt work for you as you expected.

Comment: @robbiem610 any news ?

Comment: I am passing the username from the application fine this is the my SQL that

Comment: SELECT `routine`.`RoutineName`, `routine`.`Description`
FROM `user_routines`, `routine`, `userdetails`
Where 'user_routine'.'userid' = 'user'.'userid'
AND 'user'.username = username = ?; (? is the variable passed from the application)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RoutineName, Description
FROM Routine r , UserRoutines ur
WHERE r.RoutineID = ur.RoutineID
AND userid = ?
```

Bind this request with your userID which you can stock when connecting in `$_SESSION` variable :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = the user id
```

Note : you can store username instead of userid, you'll just have to add another table to your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with your questions, this is not a "do this for me" site.

Basically you should try something like `SELECT maintable.field1, table1.field1, table2.field1 FROM MainTable INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id = Maintable.id_table1 INNER JOIN table2 INNER JOIN table2.id = Maintable.id_table2 WHERE Maintable.field1 = ?`

Comment: So, where does the "where user equals to" come into play?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I supposed that he wants to check a list of all users routines. If he  wants a particular user he has to add a where clause after the query like `WHERE userid = ?`

Comment: OP states: *"based on what they userID or username is"*